# Testing whether an event has happened after a period of time in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xforms

I'm writing a script for a form-faces xforms product that is keyed off an event built into form faces. The event is called 'xforms-ready'. I have define 'startTime' as happening as soon as the document in 'ready'. What I want the script to do is warn the user that it is taking too long before the 'xforms-ready' happens, say if it's been 6 seconds since 'startTime'. I can easily do things when the 'xforms-ready' event happens using the code below:

```
new EventListener(document.documentElement,
  "xforms-ready",
  "default",
  function() {
    var endTime = (new Date()).getTime();
  }
);
```

however the warning will want to happen before 'endTime' is defined. So I guess I want something that works like this:

```
If 6 seconds has passed since startTime and endTime is not yet defined do X
```

or possibly more efficiently:

```
If 6 seconds has passed since startTime and 'xforms-ready' has not yet happened do X
```

Can anyone suggest a way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `setTimeout`. (Complete example below.) In jQuery's `ready` handler, set a function to be called in six seconds via `setTimeout`, and in your xforms ready handler, cancel that via `clearTimeout` if it hasn't happened yet.

**Edit** Complete example (rather than my earlier fragmented code snippets), assumes it's okay if your xforms ready handler is *within* your jQuery `ready` handler:

```
jQuery.ready(function() {
    var xformsReadyTimer;

    xformsReadyTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        // Too long, show the warning
        xformsReadyTimer = undefined;
        alert("XForms is taking too long!");
    }, 6000);

    new EventListener(document.documentElement,
      "xforms-ready",
      "default",
      function() {
          if (xformsReadyTimer) {
              // Cancel the warning
              clearTimeout(xformsReadyTimer);
              xformsReadyTimer = undefined;
          }
      }
    );
});
```

(You might consider making those named functions rather than [anonymous ones](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/anonymouses-anonymous.html), but I've used anonymous ones above for simplicity.)